# Good practices for Rails website with lots of photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a website with tons of photos, and it displays them right when you visit it.  What are some best practices for displaying these photos within a rails app.

I have done your typical uploading to aws, and resizing using paperclip.  What I am looking for is other gems out there or servers that could help the website load faster, etc.

Comment: It is not specifically about Rails, you must be worried about how to store your photos. Are you using a relational database or NoSQL engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your asset loading up amongst multiple hostnames.  Create assets0, assets1, assets2, and assets3 as CNAMEs that point to your website.  Then add this to `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host      = 'https://assets%d.yourdomain.com'
config.action_mailer.asset_host          = 'https://assets%d.yourdomain.com'
```

Assets will now be loaded from one of four CNAME's.  This will trick browsers into running more requests simultaneously as most browsers limit the number of simultaneous requests to a single server.

See here for more:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html
http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/